# How to authenticate by Access Token in code using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I have a REST API and I need to authenticate users via Facebook Login API. Access Token should be obtained in mobile app (I guess) and then sent to the server. So I have found some code in old tutorial and I can't make it work. Here's the code:

```
from social.apps.django_app.utils import strategy
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework import permissions, status
from django.http import HttpResponse as Response


@strategy()
def auth_by_token(request, backend):
    user=request.user
    user = backend.do_auth(
        access_token=request.DATA.get('access_token'),
        user=user.is_authenticated() and user or None
        )
    if user and user.is_active:
        return user
    else:
        return None



@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def social_register(request):
    auth_token = request.DATA.get('access_token', None)
    backend = request.DATA.get('backend', None)
    if auth_token and backend:
        try:
            user = auth_by_token(request, backend)
        except Exception, err:
            return Response(str(err), status=400)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return Response("User logged in", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response("Bad Credentials", status=403)
    else:
        return Response("Bad request", status=400)
```

When I try to send POST request with parameters, I get this error:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'do_auth'
```

I found an example in [official documentation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token), it uses `@psa('social:complete')` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

from social.apps.django_app.utils import psa

# Define an URL entry to point to this view, call it passing the
# access_token parameter like ?access_token=<token>. The URL entry must
# contain the backend, like this:
#
#   url(r'^register-by-token/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$',
#       'register_by_access_token')

@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    # This view expects an access_token GET parameter, if it's needed,
    # request.backend and request.strategy will be loaded with the current
    # backend and strategy.
    token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    user = backend.do_auth(request.GET.get('access_token'))
    if user:
        login(request, user)
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'ERROR'
```

But what if I need to pass backend name in request body?

Comment: It should be ``request.backend.do_auth(request.GET.get('access_token'))``, I've updated the docs with the right snippet.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `request.backend.do_auth(request.GET.get('access_token'))`.

I've updated the docs with the right snippet <strike>http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token</strike> https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token.

Comment: I needed to added request=request to the do_auth arguments -- without this the pipeline social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session was causing the authorization flow to not return a user.  @omab if you think is valid, please update the docs -- it took me two days to debug this!

Comment: I am getting this error 
   ** 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:
     https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
    access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxOCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJzdWppdC50d3IiLCJleHAiOjE1MjE2NTcyMDAsImVtYWlsIjoic3VqaXQudHdyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.afmBMCZ3M00vUgGS246_yOL6XTYEYI66-BU-yUAAguY**
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can now authenticate your users against your django-rest-framework with bearer tokens/third party access tokens from any python-social-auth backend (Facebook, Google, Github, etc.) using this library https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2